# Embedding Video Code with PHP

Tags: php, video

I am developing a web application with backend administration panel that allows users to insert video embedding code. This code will render the video on the corresponding page as i am echoing that code at that location.

The problem is that, when i echo the code, the code itself gets displayed instead of video being shown. Where i am going wrong?

Here is the code entered by user in the textarea in admin panel:

```
<pre>
<object id="vp110mFH" width="432" height="240" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"><param name="movie" value="http://static.animoto.com/swf/w.swf?w=swf/vp1&e=1340255540&f=10mFH15tm8Wyv1UT85DhEA&d=72&m=p&r=360p&volume=100&start_res=360p&i=m&ct=Click...To%20request%20more%20Info..&cu=http://schoolanduniversity.com/study_programs/more-information.php&options="></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed id="vp110mFH" src="http://static.animoto.com/swf/w.swf?w=swf/vp1&e=1340255540&f=10mFH15tm8Wyv1UT85DhEA&d=72&m=p&r=360p&volume=100&start_res=360p&i=m&ct=Click...To%20request%20more%20Info..&cu=http://schoolanduniversity.com/study_programs/more-information.php&options=" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="432" height="240"></embed></object>
</pre>
```

Please guide.

Regards,
Mrinal Purohit

Comment: Can you post a sample data (code inserted by users)?

Comment: unable to add the code here....may be not allowed here. It starts like this: <object id="vp110mFH" width="432" height="240" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-4445535400................

Comment: @bmrinal - I'm more interested in how you actually store and retrieve the embed code from your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are displaying the html entities for your embed code, you could try using [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/function.html-entity-decode.php) to get around this. Of course a better solution would be to store the embed code in the correct format, ie not encoded as entities.